# How to sum grouped elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have this vector

```
v <- c(1:100)
```

And I want to get this:

```
b[1] = sum (v[c(1:10)])
b[2] = sum (v[c(11:20)])
...
...
```

I can do a loop to solve this, but I am pretty sure there is a "R way" that should be something like:

```
b <- groupedSum(v, 10)
```

where b will be a vector which will have each group of 10 summed 
What is the R way?

Comment: 1) create your grouping variable however is appropriate for your application, 2) use `plyr` or `data.table` or base function `aggregate`. Search the `plyr` tag for several examples that will be relevant.

Comment: Read this: http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/12/16/a-quick-primer-on-split-apply-combine-problems/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> tapply( v, (seq_along(v)-1) %/% 10, sum)
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
 55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

If there were NA's in there you might need to add na.rm=TRUE to the argument list after `sum`.

Comments: I think Tyler's approach is more complete because it provided better documentation. It suffers from needing to work around the vagaries of the `cut()` function which I have always felt had the wrong defaults. In order to create a grouping that captures all of 1:100 he needs to use a 101 element vector. But that's not Tyler's fault. Send him any further votes, his answer is better.

If gsk can use by-objects without running into class difficulties, he's a better man than I. The output looks like a list but it's really something different. Using his example:

```
> is.list(by(v,idx,sum))
[1] FALSE
> is.matrix(by(v,idx,sum))
[1] FALSE
> is.vector(by(v,idx,sum))
[1] FALSE
```

I think by-objects are sort of like named vectors and sort of like matrices but the failure to inherit matrix class has always confused the heck out of me.

Comment: Noted :-).  But it turns out that for a single grouping variable it's just a vector: `as.numeric(by(v,idx,sum))`

Comment: I'd do tapply(1:100, rep(1:10, each=10), sum)

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Make an index for groups:

```
N <- 50
size <- 10 # Size of a group
v <- seq(N)
idx <- as.factor(rep(seq(N/size),each=size))
```

Step 2: Use any number of vectorized tools (by, plyr, etc.) to sum over the groups:

```
by(v,idx,sum)
```

Step 3: Profit

```
idx: 1
[1] 55
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
idx: 2
[1] 155
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
idx: 3
[1] 255
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
idx: 4
[1] 355
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
idx: 5
[1] 455
```

Answer (score 3):

There's already two good methods.  I propose the use of cut to give you a range in the output:

```
v <- c(1:100) 
dat <- data.frame(v=v, cat = cut(v, seq(0, 100, by=10)))
aggregate(v~cat, data=dat, sum)
```

**Yielding:**

```
        cat   v
1    (0,10]  55
2   (10,20] 155
3   (20,30] 255
4   (30,40] 355
5   (40,50] 455
6   (50,60] 555
7   (60,70] 655
8   (70,80] 755
9   (80,90] 855
10 (90,100] 955
```

Answer (score 3):

A much faster method (20-300 times quicker compared to methods above) for larger datasets is to cast as a matrix and then use colSums.

```
> colSums( matrix( v, nrow = 10, ncol = 10 ))
 [1]  55 155 255 355 455 555 655 755 855 955
```

Consider the larger dataset

```
> n_per_group = 1e3
> n_groups    = 1e3;  
> v = 1:(n_per_group * n_groups)
```

using the matrix method takes 5ms

```
> start = Sys.time();
> r1 =colSums( matrix( v, nrow = n_per_group, ncol = n_groups ))
> end = Sys.time()
> end-start
Time difference of 0.005604982 secs
```

using the tapply method takes 601ms

```
> start = Sys.time();
> r2 = as.numeric( tapply( v, (seq_along( v ) - 1) %/% n_per_group, sum ) )
> end = Sys.time()
> end-start
Time difference of 0.6015229 secs
> all.equal( r1, r2)
 [1] TRUE
```

using the by method takes 103ms

```
> start = Sys.time();
> idx = as.factor( rep( seq( n_groups ), each = n_per_group ) )
> r3 = as.numeric(by(v,idx,sum))
> end = Sys.time() 
> end-start
Time difference of 0.1034958 secs
> all.equal( r1, r3)
 [1] TRUE
```

using the dataframe method takes 1675ms

```
> start = Sys.time();
> dat <- data.frame(v=v, cat = cut(v, seq(0, n_per_group * n_groups, by= n_per_group )))
> r4 = aggregate(v~cat, data=dat, sum)$v
> end = Sys.time()
> end-start
Time difference of 1.675465 secs
> all.equal( r1, r4)
[1] TRUE
```

and using the spares matrix method takes 334ms

```
> library( Matrix )
> start = Sys.time();
> f     = gl( n_groups, n_per_group )
> r5    = as( f, "sparseMatrix" ) %*% v
> r5    = as.numeric( r5[ , 1 ] )
> end   = Sys.time()
> end-start
Time difference of 0.334847 secs
> all.equal( r1, r5)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires Matrix library.

```
v <- seq(100)# example data
f <- gl(10,10)# generate factor for grouping
v_sums <- as(f,"sparseMatrix") %*% v
```