# How to aggregate over many columns in r?

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm new at r and this website. I have copied a sample of my data below. Basically, I have data that has 29 variables/columns and I have 30 unique row values. I want to aggregate over all the columns that are not community (all but one column). Is there a simpler way to do this? I was going to use:

```
newdf <- aggregate (Column 1 + Column 2 + Column 3 .... Column 29 ~ Community, df, sum)
```

However this is rather tedious and prone to mistakes. Is there another way to do this? Sorry if this has been asked before I couldn't find another post.

```
Community, Total.Pop., Female.Pop., Male.Pop., White.Alone.
Aleutians, 2697, 1750, 947, 64                                    
Aleutians, 1182, 6831, 499, 2952                                      
Aleutians, 4283, 2830, 1453, 1893                              
Anchorage, 4835, 2477, 2358, 4186                              
Anchorage, 4472, 2278, 2194, 3968
```

This is what I would ideally like:

```
Community, Total.Pop., Female.Pop., Male.Pop., White.Alone.
Aleutians, 8162, 11411, 2899, 4909
Anchorage, 9307, 4755, 4552, 8154
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1661144/7508461) original or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068290/7508461) on the `mtcars` example from a few minutes ago. In your case this would be `aggregate(.~ Community, df, sum)`

Comment: This would do it... `aggregate(df[,-1],by=list(df$Community.),sum)`

Comment: @Numb3rs thank you it worked out well! does this question need to be deleted or does it stay up?